# Need Java help to set and return a string

Tags: java

I am new to java trying to complete an introductory course and am really struggling. I have included the code I believe should be working but when i run the test they fail and return null.
can anyone help to see what is wrong with my code?
thank you so much

```
public class CustomString {
    String myString;
    boolean isSet;

    public CustomString() {
        this.myString = (null);
        this.isSet = (false);
    }
}
```

if the string hasn't been set with setString it should return null. setString should set the value of the current string and set this.isSet to true. and if the given string is null, sets this.isSet to false

```
public String getString() {
    if (this.myString == null || this.isSet == false) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return this.myString;
    }
}

public void setString(String string) {
    if (this.myString == null) {
        this.isSet = false;
    } else {
        this.isSet = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few pointers on the code generally:

- You don't need to use `this.foo` unless `foo` is already defined in the method's scope
- You don't need brackets around `(null)` or `(false)`
- If myString is not set, it will be null, so the logic in getString is useless, as just `return myString` would have the same result, unless isSet can be changed in a way other than setString

As for the issue, setString doesn't actually set the string, you'd need to add `myString = string` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

> *setString should set the value of the current string and set this.isSet to true. and if the given string is null, sets this.isSet to false*

You are describing that `setString()` should:

- Save the new string value (if it isn't null) and also record a value of "true" for `isSet`
- Record a value of "false" for `isSet` if the input string is "null"

Your code was close. But instead of checking `this.myString == null`, you will want to check against the input value (I named it "newString" below). Also, if that input string is non-null, you weren't saving that "newString" value anywhere; you can see that the code below does save the new string with `this.myString = newString`.

```
public void setString(String newString) {
    if (newString == null) {
        this.isSet = false;
        // seems like a good idea to also do: this.myString = null;
    } else {
        this.isSet = true;
        this.myString = newString;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `boolean isSet` is needed here, because any `Object`-reference, including `String`, is `null` by default so you can just say `if (newString != null) myString = newString`.

Comment: OP stated they are to set “isSet” to true or false depending on things, so that’s what this answer is doing.

Comment: technically yes, but at the state of your answer, `isSet` is equivalent to `myString != null`, and it is a really bad idea to store information twice. It would make sense if `myString` was always set, because `isSet && myString == null` could be true.

Comment: The excerpt at top of this answer is from OP’s requirements. It does not seem useful or helpful to OP to debate whether those requirements are good or could be improved. The entire question was stated as part of a school assignment. Such questions are often not real problems, but designed to get students to jump through specific hoops in some specific manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have the logic now on setter-level. Perhaps it placed better on the getter-level (less logic required).

```java
public class CustomString {

    private String myString = null;

    public boolean isSet() {
        return myString != null;
    }

    public void setString(String newValue) {
        myString = newValue;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

And now you can shortcut your whole class with lombok.

```java
@Data
public class CustomString {

    private String myString;

    public boolean isSet() {
        return myString != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two problems in the method setString.

1. You need set the string in the attribute myString
2. You need check if the "string" value is null, and not "myString"

Some like that:

```
public void setString(String string) {
        if (this.string == null) {
           this.isSet = false;
        } else {
           this.isSet = true;
           this.myString = string;
        }
}
```

Comment: Put `this.myString = string` at the top (or at the end, doesn't matter) outside the `if`. Otherwise, you can't set it `null`.